# How to fill a column of a certain field which has a certain Id in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to access a row that has a certain id and add new values in this row, but not in the id column. The id is used only to locate the correct row.

```
`SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into data(FirstNameOfChild,LastNameOfChild,Age) values(@FirstNameOfChild,@LastNameOfChild,@Age) where Id = @TransitionPhone.Id", con3);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstNameOfChild", childNameBOX.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastNameOfChild", lastChildBOX.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", ageBOX.Text);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

My problem is that I do not know how to access this specific id. My current attempt is the `where Id` command, which outputs an error. `TransitionPhone.Id` is an integer containing the id that I want.

Comment: INSERT queries usually don't have a WHERE clause.  If you are trying to change the values, use an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of insert, you want to do an update. You'll also need to add the ID as a parameter for the where clause.

```
"update data set FirstNameOfChild=@FirstNameOfChild,LastNameOfChild=@LastNameOfChild,Age=@Age where Id = @TransitionPhoneId"
```

Keep the parameters you're already adding and add the ID parameter as well:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransitionPhoneId", TransitionPhone.Id);
```

Comment: Of course it was update instead of insert... It worked as it was intended to. Many thanks!